# Transferring eth from a geth/attach wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, transfer

A few years ago I made a miner for ETH. I set up a wallet using geth/attach and started mining. Being a total noob, I didn't/don't know what I was/am doing so I have problems accessing my eth. So the question is, can I still access the ETH after the merge, and where can I find info on how to do this. Ideally I want to transfer the few ETH to an exchange to start trading with them. Is this possible?

Comment: Anyone with insight into this? Anything helps :)

Comment: Yes. You should be able to use any wallet that supports private keys to transfer the ether to an exchange. The merge didn't change the behavior of existing wallets.